# Right-clicking on a mathjax link does wrong thing

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, mathjax, hyperlinks

Surely I am not the only user of this site with this habit - if I want to have look at the linked content I right-click on the link to open it in a new tab, so when I finish reading I then turn to the new tab.

However if the link entirely consists of MathJax code, instead of what I want a MathJax settings menu appears (in Chrome, I don't know whether with other browsers it is the same).

Admittedly this is a rare situation, I encountered it a couple of times - e. g. there are several such links on the page of the question [Fundamental Examples](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4994/fundamental-examples); also I am aware that Ctrl-click still works in these cases. Nevertheless, my question is whether it is technically possible to activate MathJax menu only if the code is not that of a link consisting entirely of MathJax.

Comment: It is good to chose some specific tags too. (I removed the "bug" to have some more space and as it is not technically a "bug".  Note that thus tagged question actually enter a bug-tracker.)

Comment: @quid Thanks, that last circumstance did not occur to me

Comment: A middle button/scroll wheel click will typically open links in a new tab, and does not interact in any special way with the MathJax.

Comment: @BenBarber wow thanks I would never expect that! Of course the only reason I preferred right-click-menu over control-click was that I did not need keyboard, so this is even better!

Comment: Does wrong-clicking do the right thing?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is well-known, see for example the [second item in this post on a site close by](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/).

I suppose it would be technically possible, however I am a bit against it, as it adds a layer of complexity that seems not warranted to me. Moreover, it would cause an issue on how to access the MathJax menu in that case.

A way to a solution could be to try to convince user not to have MathJax-only link-text. For example, this practice is promoted on math.se (see link above, for example).